# Why were some of Iron Man’s armor not in the Marvel movies?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

So as per the comics, Tony has many suits, even suits to fight gods, but why were they not in the movies, like no Model Prime, Endo-Sym, etc.

Comment: "why were they not in the movies". I am stating the obvious, but the suits were not in the comics before they were introduced. Maybe Model Prime, etc will be featured in future movies.

Answer (score 5):

Because they weren’t needed for the MCU or didn’t make sense for the story or where the MCU was headed. Tony already has a *lot* of suits in the MCU with a lot being destroyed in *Iron Man 3* with the Clean Slate Protocol. However, all of the suits were pretty much the same base idea: a metal suit with thrusters and an arc reactor but optimised for different purposes.

The exception is with the *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame* suits using nano technology but they’re just an advanced version of the suits we previously saw.

So why not those other suits? Well the Endo-Sym suit was only created for the comics in 2014 and first shown in 2015 which is after *Iron Man 3* released so the extreme of other suits has already gone. It is also a biological suit which isn’t the way the MCU went for Iron Man, he was based on technology only, not biology.

The Model Prime suit is actually nano technology so one could argue it inspired the *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame* suits and so was in the movie just not under that name.